# GORM - Howto create a criteria query with a self referencing left outer join

Tags: sql, grails, left-join, grails-orm, self-join

I have a database table that has the following structure:

```
table Transaction {
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
  , group VARCHAR(10)
  , subgroup VARCHAR(8)
  , createdOn DATETIME
}
```

I have a need to find all the latest transactions by group/subgroup in my application.  I know how I can achieve this in pure SQL.  However, since this is a Grails application I would like to use Gorm to achieve the same result.  I have searched both the Grails/Hibernate forums and there seems to be some similar results to my problem however none of the left outer join solutions have to deal with a self referenced join.

Here is the SQL that I am trying to replicate in Gorm

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM transaction as t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN transaction as t2 
        ON (t1.group = t2.group 
        AND t1.subgroup = t2.subgroup
        AND t1.createdOn < t2.createdOn)
 WHERE t1.group = :someUserSuppliedGroup
   AND t2.subgroup = :someOptionalUserSuppliedSubgroup
   AND t2.id IS NULL
```

Sample Data:

```
ID | Group | Subgroup | CreatedOn
 1   G1      SG1        01/01/2014 00:00:00 AM
 2   G1      SG1        01/01/2014 01:00:00 AM    
 3   G1      SG2        03/03/2014 03:00:00 PM
 4   G1      SG2        03/04/2014 03:00:00 PM
```

Expected Results

```
ID | Group | Subgroup | CreatedOn
 2   G1      SG1        01/01/2014 01:00:00 AM
 4   G1      SG2        03/04/2014 03:00:00 PM
```

I have temporarily coded a solution that does the grouping and determination of latest transaction.  This occurs after the initial database query has ran.  Obviously, I would like to refactor my code so that the database does the heavy lifting.

Thank you in advance for any insight to possible solutions.  I am also open to solutions where the SQL uses a correlated sub-query to determine the correct data as well.  I just think this SQL is simpler.